# apply same effect on different element

Tags: html, css

By using the below code , i want to apply same effect of css on h1 and h2 tag.

**HTML**

```
<div class="blog_content_snippet">
    <h1 contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter text here h1"></h1>
    <h2 contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter text here h2"></h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blog_content_snippet h1,h2:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text)
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmta3bu5/6/

Using one css i want apply on both , anyone have idea ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cmta3bu5/11/
This answer is right , but anyone have more idea or any other way ??

Comment: added an alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare both of them

```
.blog_content_snippet h1:empty:not(:focus):before,    
.blog_content_snippet h2:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text)
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmta3bu5/15/)

Or you could always just create a `class` and add it to whatever element you want:

**HTML**

```
<div class="blog_content_snippet">
   <h1 class="content" contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter text here h1"></h1>
   <h2 class="content" contentEditable="true" data-text="Enter text here h2"></h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text)
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmta3bu5/16/)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```css
.blog_content_snippet h1:empty:not(:focus):before,
.blog_content_snippet h2:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content:attr(data-text)
}
```